# нужна ли запятая после слова "восторга"

Tags: пунктуация

плачьте от умиления и восторга слагая Ему гимны.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, так как деепричастный оборот должен быть обособлен запятыми:

> Плачьте от умиления и восторга, слагая ему гимны.

Однако откуда берутся такие странные предложения, если не секрет?

Comment: это предложение из области выражения искреннего чувства любви к Творцу для верующих, религиозной экзальтации

Comment: Необычно тут у вас. )